# Add SubCategories to Categories array

Tags: javascript

I have a `Category` object, each `Category` has `SubCategories`. What would be the right way to load for each `Category` its `SubCategories`?

```
const getCategories = async () => {
  const { data: categories } = await axios.get(`api/Categories/GetCategories`); 
  return categories;
};

const getSubCategories = async catId => {
  const { data: subCategories } = await axios.get(`../api/SubCategories/GetSubCategories?catId=${catId}`); 
  return subCategories;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple but suboptimal method because of the lack of asynchronicity.

```
const categories = getCategories().map(category => {
    return {
        category
        , subCategory: getSubCategories(category.catId)
    }
})
```

A better way would be to remove the `await` from `getSubCategories` and have it just return the promise.

```
const getSubCategories = async catId => axios.get(`../api/SubCategories/GetSubCategories?catId=${catId}`)
```

When you return promises, they can run asynchronously.

```
const categories = getCategories()
```

If you're in an async function you can do:

```
const subCategories = await Promise.all(categories.map(category => getSubCategories(category.catId))
const categoriesWithSub = zipWith(categories, subCategories, (category, subCategory) => ({category, subCategory}))
```

Otherwise

```
Promise.all(categories.map(category => getSubCategories(category.catId))
.then(subCategories => {
    const categoriesWithSub = zipWith(categories, subCategories, (category, subCategory) => ({category, subCategory}))
})
```

`categoriesWithSub` is an array of objects with the following shape.

```
[{
    category: {} // however your original category object looked like.
    , subCategory: [] // The array of subCategories for this category.
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain how does the `zipWith` works? I basically need to have an array of `categories`, each `category` object should has an array of `subCategories`

Comment: In this case zipWith returns an array of objects, each with two properties, category and subCategories. I'll update answer.

Comment: Thank you, however subCategories is always empty `{}`

Comment: Doh, yes, I forgot one thing. Promise.all returns a promise not the array. Updating answer. Coding blind isn't easy